# How can I resolve "invalid response ... from upstream server" in Kong ingress with KeyCloak?

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, minikube, kong, kong-ingress

I have managed to run KeyCloak and Kong on minikube with kubernetes-version='v1.13.11'.

I'm using this version because I want to deploy to GCP cluster eventually.

When I try to open PROXY_IP:HTTP_PORT/auth I get following response:

```
**"Kong Error An invalid response was received from the 
upstream server."**
```

What I think I should get is KeyCloak homepage.

Steps to reproduce:

1. `minikube start --kubernetes-version='v1.13.11'`
2. `kubectl apply -f keycloack.yaml`
3. `kubectl apply -f kong-all-in-one.yaml`
4. `kubectl apply -f kong-ingress.yaml`
5. `export PROXY_IP=$(minikube service kong-proxy --url --format "{{ .IP }}" | head -1)`
6. `export HTTP_PORT=$(minikube service kong-proxy --url --format "{{ .Port }}" | head -1)`
7. Visit `$PROXY_IP:$HTTP_PORT/auth`

**keycloak.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: keycloak-db
  name: keycloak-db
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 5432
  selector:
    app: keycloak-db
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  labels:
    app: keycloak-datastore
  name: keycloak-datastore
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: keycloak-db
  name: keycloak-db
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak-db
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: POSTGRES_DB
          value: keycloak
        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          value: password
        - name: POSTGRES_USER
          value: keycloak
        image: postgres:9.6
        name: keycloak-db
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/postresql/key/data
          name: keycloak-datastore
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
      - name: keycloak-datastore
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: keycloak-datastore
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: keycloak-service
  name: keycloak-service
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8383
    targetPort: 8080
  - name: https
    port: 8443
    targetPort: 8443
  selector:
    app: keycloak
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keycloak-http
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
          value: "true"
        - name: DB_ADDR
          value: keycloak-db
        - name: DB_DATABASE
          value: keycloak
        - name: DB_PASSWORD
          value: password
        - name: DB_USER
          value: keycloak
        - name: DB_VENDOR
          value: postgres
        - name: KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL
          value: DEBUG
        - name: KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD
          value: admin
        - name: KEYCLOAK_USER
          value: admin
        - name: POSTGRES_PORT
          value: "5432"
        image: jboss/keycloak:8.0.1
        name: keycloak
        ports:
          - name: http
            containerPort: 8080
          - name: https
            containerPort: 8443
      restartPolicy: Always
```

**kong-all-in-one.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: kongconsumers.configuration.konghq.com
spec:
  additionalPrinterColumns:
  - JSONPath: .username
    description: Username of a Kong Consumer
    name: Username
    type: string
  - JSONPath: .metadata.creationTimestamp
    description: Age
    name: Age
    type: date
  group: configuration.konghq.com
  names:
    kind: KongConsumer
    plural: kongconsumers
    shortNames:
    - kc
  scope: Namespaced
  validation:
    openAPIV3Schema:
      properties:
        credentials:
          items:
            type: string
          type: array
        custom_id:
          type: string
        username:
          type: string
  version: v1
---
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: kongcredentials.configuration.konghq.com
spec:
  additionalPrinterColumns:
  - JSONPath: .type
    description: Type of credential
    name: Credential-type
    type: string
  - JSONPath: .metadata.creationTimestamp
    description: Age
    name: Age
    type: date
  - JSONPath: .consumerRef
    description: Owner of the credential
    name: Consumer-Ref
    type: string
  group: configuration.konghq.com
  names:
    kind: KongCredential
    plural: kongcredentials
  scope: Namespaced
  validation:
    openAPIV3Schema:
      properties:
        consumerRef:
          type: string
        type:
          type: string
      required:
      - consumerRef
      - type
  version: v1
---
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: kongingresses.configuration.konghq.com
spec:
  group: configuration.konghq.com
  names:
    kind: KongIngress
    plural: kongingresses
    shortNames:
    - ki
  scope: Namespaced
  validation:
    openAPIV3Schema:
      properties:
        proxy:
          properties:
            connect_timeout:
              minimum: 0
              type: integer
            path:
              pattern: ^/.*$
              type: string
            protocol:
              enum:
              - http
              - https
              - grpc
              - grpcs
              type: string
            read_timeout:
              minimum: 0
              type: integer
            retries:
              minimum: 0
              type: integer
            write_timeout:
              minimum: 0
              type: integer
          type: object
        route:
          properties:
            headers:
              additionalProperties:
                items:
                  type: string
                type: array
              type: object
            https_redirect_status_code:
              type: integer
            methods:
              items:
                type: string
              type: array
            preserve_host:
              type: boolean
            protocols:
              items:
                enum:
                - http
                - https
                - grpc
                - grpcs
                type: string
              type: array
            regex_priority:
              type: integer
            strip_path:
              type: boolean
        upstream:
          properties:
            algorithm:
              enum:
              - round-robin
              - consistent-hashing
              - least-connections
              type: string
            hash_fallback:
              type: string
            hash_fallback_header:
              type: string
            hash_on:
              type: string
            hash_on_cookie:
              type: string
            hash_on_cookie_path:
              type: string
            hash_on_header:
              type: string
            healthchecks:
              properties:
                active:
                  properties:
                    concurrency:
                      minimum: 1
                      type: integer
                    healthy:
                      properties:
                        http_statuses:
                          items:
                            type: integer
                          type: array
                        interval:
                          minimum: 0
                          type: integer
                        successes:
                          minimum: 0
                          type: integer
                      type: object
                    http_path:
                      pattern: ^/.*$
                      type: string
                    timeout:
                      minimum: 0
                      type: integer
                    unhealthy:
                      properties:
                        http_failures:
                          minimum: 0
                          type: integer
                        http_statuses:
                          items:
                            type: integer
                          type: array
                        interval:
                          minimum: 0
                          type: integer
                        tcp_failures:
                          minimum: 0
                          type: integer
                        timeout:
                          minimum: 0
                          type: integer
                      type: object
                  type: object
                passive:
                  properties:
                    healthy:
                      properties:
                        http_statuses:
                          items:
                            type: integer
                          type: array
                        interval:
                          minimum: 0
                          type: integer
                        successes:
                          minimum: 0
                          type: integer
                      type: object
                    unhealthy:
                      properties:
                        http_failures:
                          minimum: 0
                          type: integer
                        http_statuses:
                          items:
                            type: integer
                          type: array
                        interval:
                          minimum: 0
                          type: integer
                        tcp_failures:
                          minimum: 0
                          type: integer
                        timeout:
                          minimum: 0
                          type: integer
                      type: object
                  type: object
              type: object
            host_header:
              type: string
            slots:
              minimum: 10
              type: integer
          type: object
  version: v1
---
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: kongplugins.configuration.konghq.com
spec:
  additionalPrinterColumns:
  - JSONPath: .plugin
    description: Name of the plugin
    name: Plugin-Type
    type: string
  - JSONPath: .metadata.creationTimestamp
    description: Age
    name: Age
    type: date
  - JSONPath: .disabled
    description: Indicates if the plugin is disabled
    name: Disabled
    priority: 1
    type: boolean
  - JSONPath: .config
    description: Configuration of the plugin
    name: Config
    priority: 1
    type: string
  group: configuration.konghq.com
  names:
    kind: KongPlugin
    plural: kongplugins
    shortNames:
    - kp
  scope: Namespaced
  validation:
    openAPIV3Schema:
      properties:
        config:
          type: object
        disabled:
          type: boolean
        plugin:
          type: string
        protocols:
          items:
            enum:
            - http
            - https
            - grpc
            - grpcs
            - tcp
            - tls
            type: string
          type: array
        run_on:
          enum:
          - first
          - second
          - all
          type: string
      required:
      - plugin
  version: v1
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: kong-serviceaccount
  namespace: default
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: kong-ingress-clusterrole
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - endpoints
  - nodes
  - pods
  - secrets
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - nodes
  verbs:
  - get
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - services
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - networking.k8s.io
  - extensions
  resources:
  - ingresses
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - events
  verbs:
  - create
  - patch
- apiGroups:
  - networking.k8s.io
  - extensions
  resources:
  - ingresses/status
  verbs:
  - update
- apiGroups:
  - configuration.konghq.com
  resources:
  - kongplugins
  - kongcredentials
  - kongconsumers
  - kongingresses
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resourceNames:
  - ingress-controller-leader-kong
  resources:
  - configmaps
  verbs:
  - get
  - update
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - configmaps
  verbs:
  - create
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: kong-ingress-clusterrole-nisa-binding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: kong-ingress-clusterrole
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: kong-serviceaccount
  namespace: default
---
apiVersion: v1
data:
  servers.conf: |
    # Prometheus metrics server
    server {
        server_name kong_prometheus_exporter;
        listen 0.0.0.0:9542; # can be any other port as well
        access_log off;

        location /metrics {
            default_type text/plain;
            content_by_lua_block {
                 local prometheus = require "kong.plugins.prometheus.exporter"
                 prometheus:collect()
            }
        }

        location /nginx_status {
            internal;
            stub_status;
        }
    }
    # Health check server
    server {
        server_name kong_health_check;
        listen 0.0.0.0:9001; # can be any other port as well

        access_log off;
        location /health {
          return 200;
        }
    }
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: kong-server-blocks
  namespace: default
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
  name: kong-proxy
  namespace: default
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
  - name: proxy
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8000
  - name: proxy-ssl
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8443
  selector:
    app: ingress-kong
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kong-validation-webhook
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - name: webhook
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: ingress-kong
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: ingress-kong
  name: ingress-kong
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ingress-kong
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/port: "9542"
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
        traffic.sidecar.istio.io/includeInboundPorts: ""
      labels:
        app: ingress-kong
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: KONG_DATABASE
          value: "off"
        - name: KONG_NGINX_WORKER_PROCESSES
          value: "1"
        - name: KONG_NGINX_HTTP_INCLUDE
          value: /kong/servers.conf
        - name: KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG
          value: /dev/stdout
        - name: KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG
          value: /dev/stderr
        - name: KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN
          value: 127.0.0.1:8444 ssl
        - name: KONG_PROXY_LISTEN
          value: 0.0.0.0:8000, 0.0.0.0:8443 ssl http2
        image: kong:1.4
        lifecycle:
          preStop:
            exec:
              command:
              - /bin/sh
              - -c
              - kong quit
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /health
            port: 9001
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        name: proxy
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
          name: proxy
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8443
          name: proxy-ssl
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9542
          name: metrics
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /health
            port: 9001
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 1000
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /kong
          name: kong-server-blocks
      - args:
        - /kong-ingress-controller
        - --kong-url=https://localhost:8444
        - --admin-tls-skip-verify
        - --publish-service=default/kong-proxy
        env:
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        image: kong-docker-kubernetes-ingress-controller.bintray.io/kong-ingress-controller:0.7.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10254
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        name: ingress-controller
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: webhook
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10254
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
      serviceAccountName: kong-serviceaccount
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          name: kong-server-blocks
        name: kong-server-blocks
```

**kong-ingress.yaml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: keycloak-ingress
spec:
  rules:
   - http:
      paths:
      - path: /auth
        backend:
          serviceName: keycloak-service
          servicePort: 8383
```

**UPDATE in response to comment:**

```
$ kubectl describe ingress keycloak-ingress
Name:             keycloak-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:          
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<none>)
Rules:
  Host  Path  Backends
  ----  ----  --------
  *     
        /auth   keycloak-service:80 (<none>)
Annotations:
  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:  {"apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"keycloak-ingress","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"rules":[{"http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"serviceName":"keycloak-service","servicePort":80},"path":"/auth"}]}}]}}
```

Comment: Can you post output from `kubectl describe ingress keycloak-ingress`?

Comment: @Crou hey I have  added "kubectl describe ingress keycloak-ingress" to question so it's easier to read

Comment: keycloack.yaml ? really with the typo?

Comment: Your `ingress` will not work because it's pointing to a port `80` which is not exposed by your **keycloak-service** `service`.

Comment: @Crou I have changes ingress port to 8383 but still getting the same error.

Comment: If you are creating `ingress` you should access the app using `ingress` IP not `service`. You should first test if keycloak is deployed correctly without kong. If your `ingress` doesn't have IP then it's not working correctly.

Comment: Same problem here. Did you fix it?